# Como fazer com que o menuItem (RadioButton) seja seleccionado de acordo com o tipo de mapa?

Tags: android, menu

Tenho um Fragment que dá erro sempre que eu inicio ele.
Ele gera o seguinte erro:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.getMapType()' on a null object reference
        at mz.co.bm.bmtrack.MapFragment.onPrepareOptionsMenu(MapFragment.java:175)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performPrepareOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:2475)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu(FragmentManager.java:3295)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu(FragmentController.java:331)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPreparePanel(FragmentActivity.java:480)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:98)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onPreparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:359)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:98)
        at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$ToolbarCallbackWrapper.onPreparePanel(ToolbarActionBar.java:522)
        at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:456)
        at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:57)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:618)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Nesse código:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mesmo colocando essas verificações no onCreateOptionMenu, gera o mesmo erro.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse erro é gerado quando clico sobre o Location na BottomNavigationView.
O Listener da BottomNavigation é a seguinte:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.btm_route:
                    // TODO

                    getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.fragment, new RotaFragment())
                            .commit();


                    return true;
                case R.id.btm_localizacao:
                    // TODO

                    getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.fragment, new MapFragment())
                            .commit();

                    return true;
                case R.id.btm_fuel:
                    // TODO

                    getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.fragment, new FuelFragment())
                            .commit();

                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Você diz que dá erro quando inicia o Fragment mas depois diz que é quando clica no botão. Qual das duas é?

Comment: É quando clico no botão e, logo dá erro! Me desculpe pela confusão!

Comment: O erro indica que a variável `map` é nula.

Comment: É! Mas, ela foi incializada! Tanto que, quando eu inicio a app, ela abre normalmente, o problema é quando cliclo nesses botões! Não entendo o que está errado!

Comment: Adicione na pergunta o código completo relevante ao seu problema

Comment: Adicionei o Listener da BottomNavigationView, não sei ainda preciso adicionar mais alguma coisa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já consegui resolver.
Era só criar um método para verificar se o mapa é nulo e configurar o menu posteriormente.

```
public boolean isMapNull() {
     if (map != null) {
         return false;
     } else {
         return true;
     }
}
```

E colocar ele no onPrepareOptionMenu()

```
 @Override
 public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

     if (!isMapNull()) {

         terreno = menu.findItem(R.id.terreno_maptype);
         satelite = menu.findItem(R.id.satelite_maptype);
         hibrido = menu.findItem(R.id.hibrido_maptype);

         int t = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN;
         int s = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE;
         int h = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID;

         if (map.getMapType() == t) {

             alterarTipoParaTerreno();
             terreno.setChecked(true);

         } else if (map.getMapType() == s) {

             alterarTipoParaSatelite();
             satelite.setChecked(true);

         } else if (map.getMapType() == h) {

             alterarTipoParaHibrido();
             hibrido.setChecked(true);
         }
     }

     super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
 }
```